# Bounds for mass-spring oscillator (system parameters).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation governing the motion of an
externally forced damped mass–spring oscillator:
$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{m\beta}(g*f)(t)=\frac{1}{m\beta}\int_0^te^{-bv/2m}\sin\beta v\cdot f(t-v)\,dv.
$$
How would I go about answering the following question, I've been stuck on it for some time:

c) Show that the motion $x(t)$ is bounded under these circumstances by:
$$
|x(t)|\le At/\beta m 
$$
and also by
$$
|x(t)|\le 2A/\beta b 
$$
Said circumstances are: the system is underdamped, it starts from rest, the forcing term is bounded ($|f(t)|< A$  for all $t$). Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first bound:

$$\big|x(t)\big|\leq \frac{1}{m\beta}\int_{0}^{t}\big|e^{-bv/2m}\sin{\beta v}\cdot f(t-v)\big|\,dv\leq\frac{1}{m\beta}\int_{0}^{t}A\,dv = \frac{At}{\beta m},\qquad(t>0)$$

using the fact that $\big|f(t)\big| <A$ and both $\sin{\beta v}$ and $e^{-bv/2m}$ are bounded above by 1 for $t>0$.  I'm not sure I agree with the statement of the second bound, however, because $v$ is just a dummy variable of integration and should integrate out to get something in terms of $t$ regardless of how you estimate the integrand.

Comment: The reason you don't agree with the second bound is because I had a typo hehe. Edited the original question.